# MS Access - SQL value depending of a variable text list

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a table with a column allowing multiple selected values (depending of another table)

For example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Value 1 | A, B |
| Value 2 | A, B, C |

I wanted to do a cascade combobox: if "Value 1" is choosed, then the 2nd combobox allow the values "A", "B"

I make my 2nd combobox values depending of a table/query
When I type manually the criteria In("A";"B") it works but not with my variable
I tried to change the SQL via VBA, and it works only for one value, not multiple values

Me.Expectedvalueslist is "A";"B"

```
sqlresult = "SELECT [Table 2].Type, [Table 2].Description FROM [Nomenclature documentaire] WHERE ((([Table 2].Type) In (" & Me.Expectedvalueslist & "))); "
Expectedvalueslist.Caption = sqlresult
Me.DocumentSelect.RowSource = sqlresult
```

The "sqlresult" label I create to check the string result displays exacly what I'd type but the combobox don't update (I tried with requery but shows nothing)

thanks in advance

Comment: You really need to normalise your design here, then you'll have an easier time with this.

Comment: You also need to **parametrise** your statements; you're injecting values, which is a significant security vulnerability.

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL server and ms access? They two very different databases engines

Comment: At a guess, @DaleK , the OP is using MS Access as the front end, with SQL Server as the back end. ¯\⁠_⁠(⁠ツ⁠)⁠_⁠/⁠¯

Comment: The `Row Source Type` of the ComboBox must be `Value List`. Then you can assign a value like `A;B;C`. Depending on the culture settings in your installation, you can also use commas instead of semicolons. My Access actually allows me to insert e.g., `A,  B; C` manually and the value is automatically changed to `A;B;C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want combobox to display a list like:

A
B
C

cannot set RowSource to SQL statement that returns a field with string `A,B,C`.

First combobox can have RowSource of:
`SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB FROM Table2;`

Then second combobox can have RowSource set by VBA with: `= Me.combobox1.Column(1)`
Set this combobox properties: RowSourceType of ValueList and ColumnCount of 1